# apply hpfilter to grouped variables with NAs using dplyr

Tags: r

I am trying to apply the hpfilter to one of the variables in my dataset that has a panel structure (id + year) and then add the filtered series to my dataset. It works perfectly fine as long as I do not have any NAs in one of the variables, but it yields an error if one of the ids has missing values. The reason for this is that the `hpfilter` function does not work with `NAs` (it yields only NAs).

Here's a reproducible example:

```
df1  <- read.table(text="country   year   X1  X2    W
                   A         1990   10  20    40
                   A         1991   12  15    NA
                   A         1992   14  17    41
                   A         1993   17  NA    44
                   B         1990   20  NA    45
                   B         1991   NA  13    61
                   B         1992   12  12    67
                   B         1993   14  10    68
                   C         1990   10  20    70
                   C         1991   11  14    50
                   C         1992   12  15    NA
                   C         1993   14  16    NA
                   D         1990   20  17    80
                   D         1991   16  20    91
                   D         1992   15  21    70 
                   D         1993   14  22    69
                   ", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

My approach was to use the `dplyr` `group_by` function to apply the hpfilter by country to variable `X1`:

```
library(mFilter)
library(plm)

# Organizing the Data as a Panel
df1 <- pdata.frame(df1, index = c("country","year"))

# Apply hpfilter to X1 and add trend to the sample 
df1 <- df1 %>% group_by(country) %>% mutate(X1_trend = mFilter::hpfilter(na.exclude(X1), type = "lambda", freq = 6.25)$trend)
```

However, this yields the following error:

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, col, value = c(11.1695436493374, 12.7688604220353,  : 
  replacement has 15 rows, data has 16
```

The error occurs because the filtered series is shortened after applying the hp filter (by the NAs).

Since I have a large dataset with many countries it would be really great if there was a workaround, to maybe ignore the NAs when passing the series to the hpfilter, but not removing them. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to drop `NA` and calculate `trend`:

```
df2 <- df1 %>% group_by(country) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(X1)) %>% 
  pdata.frame(., index = c("country","year")) %>% 
  mutate(X1_trend = mFilter::hpfilter(X1, type = "lambda", freq = 6.25)$trend)

> df2
   country year X1 X2  W X1_trend
1        A 1990 10 20 40 11.16954
2        A 1991 12 15 NA 12.76886
3        A 1992 14 17 41 14.18105
4        A 1993 17 NA 44 15.09597
5        B 1990 20 NA 45 15.17450
6        B 1992 12 12 67 14.38218
7        B 1993 14 10 68 13.45663
8        C 1990 10 20 70 12.75429
9        C 1991 11 14 50 12.71858
10       C 1992 12 15 NA 13.35221
11       C 1993 14 16 NA 14.38293
12       D 1990 20 17 80 15.32211
13       D 1991 16 20 91 15.61990
14       D 1992 15 21 70 15.47486
15       D 1993 14 22 69 15.14639
```

**EDIT**: To keep missing values in the final output, we do one more operation:

```
df3 <- merge(df1,df2, by = colnames(df1),all.x = T)

> df3
   country year X1 X2  W X1_trend
1        A 1990 10 20 40 11.16954
2        A 1991 12 15 NA 12.76886
3        A 1992 14 17 41 14.18105
4        A 1993 17 NA 44 15.09597
5        B 1990 20 NA 45 15.17450
6        B 1991 NA 13 61       NA
7        B 1992 12 12 67 14.38218
8        B 1993 14 10 68 13.45663
9        C 1990 10 20 70 12.75429
10       C 1991 11 14 50 12.71858
11       C 1992 12 15 NA 13.35221
12       C 1993 14 16 NA 14.38293
13       D 1990 20 17 80 15.32211
14       D 1991 16 20 91 15.61990
15       D 1992 15 21 70 15.47486
16       D 1993 14 22 69 15.14639
```

Comment: Hold on, this might not be for each `group`.

Comment: Great, this works perfectly, indeed. But is there also a way that it does not curtail the rows to 15? Note that the year 1991 in your example disappears.

Comment: Do you want a row with all `NA`instead of dropping? The reason that there is no 1991 for group B is that the value of `X1` s`NA`

Comment: Ideally, I would like to have `NA` in 1991 for variable `X1`, but not for the other variables.

Comment: I added one more line that keeps `NA` in `X1`. If this answers your question, please accept it and upvote.